# Where does the cylinder hit the side of the bucket?

Tags: geometry

I have two objects.  One is a cylinder 305mm in diameter.  The other is a bucket which is 330mm at the top and 280mm at the bottom (straight tapered).  If I insert the cylinder into the bucket, what will be the height from the bottom of the bucket where the cylinder will rest?  What is the formula to determine this as I have different size buckets to choose from?

Answer (score 1):

I assume the diameter of the bucket increases linearly (it is not bulged in or out..). If the diameter of the bucket at height $0$ is $d_1=280$mm and $d_2=330$mm at height $1$, then the diameter at height $h$ is 
$$
d=d_1 + h\cdot (d_2-d_1)
$$
Thus your cylinder fits in at height
$$
h = \frac{d-d_1}{d_2-d_1}
$$
which is $h=1/2$ for your case $d=305$mm.